# Nodejs streaming

Tags: sockets, streaming, node.js

I want to realize a simple client-server connection using Nodejs.
But I've encountered with the following problem.

Consider the code

server.js:

```
var net = require('net'),
    sys = require('sys');

    net.createServer(onConnection).listen(8124);

    function onConnection(socket) {
     socket.setNoDelay(true);

     socket.addListener("connect", function () {
      sys.puts('client connected: ' + this.remoteAddress);
     });

     socket.addListener("data", function (data) {
      sys.puts("message: \n" + data + "\n - end of msg.");
     });

     socket.addListener("end", function () {
      sys.puts('end of connection');
      this.end();
     });
    }

    sys.puts('Server running at 127.0.0.1:8124');
```

client.js:

```
var net = require('net'),
 sys = require('sys');

var stream = net.createConnection(8124);
stream.addListener("connect", function(){
 sys.puts('connected');

 stream.write('a');
    stream.flush();
 stream.write('b');
    stream.flush();

});

stream.addListener("data", function(data){
 sys.puts("Message: \n" + data + "\n - end of msg.");
});
```

When I run client.js I sometimes get only one message 'ab' instead of two messages 'a' and 'b'.

Is there some 'right method' to deal with that?

Comment: you may even receive 'ba'!! there is no grantee to receive data in the order you send them.

Comment: @MortezaM. actually TCP/IP *gives guarantee* that data will be received on the order it has been sent, so in this case it'll always be `ab`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TCP is a *stream* protocol. Single `write` on one end of the pipe can result in multiple "reads" on the other end, and the other way around. You have to either explicitly tell the other side how many bytes you are sending by including the length in the message; or provide easily recognizable message delimiters. In any case you need to read in a loop.

Comment: So, the only 'right method' is to concatenate incoming data and  parse it as a whole thing? I thought of this, just want to be sure there is no other methods :)

Comment: You have to treat it as a stream. Parse the bytes as they come, react when complete message is found.

Answer (score 0):

use socket.write return value and callback as documented here https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback to know when the data is completly flushed to the kernel . Wait for that to happen and after that call the second write. that way you make sure of the ordering. Regarding the problem of logic separartion of "a" and "b" you might want to design/implement that "protocol yourself, it's not a responsiblity of the (low-level) socket API.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you are able to structure to be a line-based text protocol, you can use `readline`.  See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#example-tiny-cli
- https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#example-read-file-stream-line-by-line