# Node.js: how to flush socket?

Tags: sockets, node.js

I'm trying to flush a socket before sending the next chunk of the data:

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}).listen(54358, '127.0.0.1');

var socket = net.createConnection(54358, '127.0.0.1');

socket.setNoDelay(true);
socket.write('mentos');
socket.write('cola');
```

This, however, doesn't work despite the `setNoDelay` option, e.g. prints "mentoscola" instead of "mentos\ncola". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking over the `WriteableStream` api, and the associated example **it seems that you should set your breaks or delimiters yourself.**

```
exports.puts = function (d) {
  process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

Because your socket is a stream, data will be written/read without your direct control, and `#write` won't change your data or assume you're meaning to break between writes, since you could be streaming a large piece of information over the socket and might want to set other delimiters.

I'm definitely no expert in this area, but that seems like the logical answer to me.

**Edit**: This is a duplicate of [Nodejs streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335092/nodejs-streaming), and the conclusion there was the same as the answer I specified: working with streams isn't line-by-line, set your own delimiters.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe all data written in the same tick is sent as a batch.

Maybe at the receiving side, the node will combine the separate data segments before emitting the data event.